# Changing route from GET to Delete in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, custom-routes

`logout GET /logout(.:format) devise/sessions#destroy`

This is the route I am interested in.

However, when I go to /logout, I get this error:

`No route matches [DELETE] "/logout"`, how do I change this route from `get` to `delete`?

This is how my route is currently set up:

`get 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout`

and my link:

`<%= link_to "Sign Out", logout_path, method: :delete %>`

Comment: Try with this <%= link_to "Sign Out", logout_path, :method=> 'delete' %>

Comment: @Debadatt, I get the same error. There is no change.

Comment: Using `delete 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout` as suggested in the answer below will get your `link_to` working. It's strange that you didn't get this route automatically with devise, though. When I run `rake routes`, I have a line `destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)                devise/sessions#destroy` and I didn't have to manually set up the route in `routes.rb`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
get 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
```

to:

```
delete 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
```

You can find more information on routing on this page: [Routing Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize it was this simple!